# How to rename the file which is in perforce depot

Tags: perforce

what is the process to rename the files in depot without getting any conflicts?

Is there any way either in p4 or command line?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, but the method depends on the version of Perforce you're running.  Here's how to do it from the command line (this is copied from the output of "p4 help rename").

```
In release 2009.1 and higher, you can use 'p4 move' to move or
rename files. Perforce clients prior to release 2009.1 do not
support 'p4 move'.  However, files in older clients can be
renamed by branching one file to another and deleting the
original file.  For example:

    p4 integrate fromFile toFile
    p4 delete fromFile
    p4 submit

For further information, see the help for the individual commands.

Note: Files renamed in this way are treated as branched files
rather than moved files in subsequent operations.
```